# what is the best way to access the AWS Aurora database from Xamarin?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, xamarin, amazon-aurora

Hi if I am using the Aurora RDS from Amazon, what would be the best way to access it from Xamarin in a cross platform app. Is there any documentation that would help? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The best way to connect to Aurora databases in RDS from Xamarin will be to use the official MySQL connector here (also includes a great example) https://components.xamarin.com/view/mysql-plugin

Make sure to point at the Cluster endpoint for any writes and to explicitly close the connection when done accessing the database.  You will also want to make sure that your Aurora instance uses a VPC security group that allows access from the location where the Xamarin app is connecting from.

The following document elaborates on the networking side of it more:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html

Comment: thanks that works. just concerned about the connector's security vulnerability as mention on the components download page!